# Segmented Control to change views

Tags: iphone, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created an up/down arrow segmented control button on the right side of the navigation bar in my detail view. In a table based application, how can I use these up/down arrows to move through cells in the parent table?

The apple "NavBar" sample code has an example of this but the controls are not functional.

The iBird program has this functionality as well and it is very nice. Download the "iBird 15" program for free.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: My thought is you should accept an answer or two so people don't feel like they are wasting their time answering your questions. Seriously, 0 accepts? Not how this place works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the segmented control to momentary mode, and set the control's action for UIControlEventValueChanged to point to your view controller. Then your view controller can change the selection in the table, or whatever it is you're doing with tables. (I'm not sure if you're using a UITableView or something else.)